issue with Automating the process of AMI in cloud formation using the lambda function
i try to achieve the Automatic creation of AMI using the Lambda function within the cloud formation but getting the error as : Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) within the specified duration
(https://i.sstatic.net/POcKO.jpg)
AMIFunction:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        Handler: index.handler
        Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
        Code:
          ZipFile: !Sub |
            import logging
            import cfnresponse
            import json
            import boto3
            from threading import Timer
            from botocore.exceptions import WaiterError

            logger = logging.getLogger()
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

            def handler(event, context):

              ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
              physicalId = event['PhysicalResourceId'] if 'PhysicalResourceId' in event else None

              def success(data={}):
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, data, physicalId)

              def failed(e):
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, str(e), physicalId)

              logger.info('Request received: %s\n' % json.dumps(event))

              try:
                instanceId = event['ResourceProperties']['InstanceId']
                if (not instanceId):
                  raise 'InstanceID required'

                if not 'RequestType' in event:
                  success({'Data': 'Unhandled request type'})
                  return
                  
                if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
                  if (not physicalId.startswith('ami-')):
                    raise 'Unknown PhysicalId: %s' % physicalId
                  
                  ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
                  images = ec2client.describe_images(ImageIds=[physicalId])
                  for image in images['Images']:
                    ec2.Image(image['ImageId']).deregister()
                    snapshots = ([bdm['Ebs']['SnapshotId'] 
                                  for bdm in image['BlockDeviceMappings'] 
                                  if 'Ebs' in bdm and 'SnapshotId' in bdm['Ebs']])
                    for snapshot in snapshots:
                      ec2.Snapshot(snapshot).delete()

                  success({'Data': 'OK'})
                elif event['RequestType'] in set(['Create', 'Update']):
                  if not physicalId:  # AMI creation has not been requested yet
                    instance = ec2.Instance(instanceId)
                    instance.wait_until_stopped()

                    image = instance.create_image(Name="Automatic from CloudFormation stack                   ${AWS::StackName}")

                    physicalId = image.image_id
                  else:
                    logger.info('Continuing in awaiting image available: %s\n' % physicalId)

                  ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
                  waiter = ec2client.get_waiter('image_available')

                  try:
                    waiter.wait(ImageIds=[physicalId], WaiterConfig={'Delay': 30, 'MaxAttempts':6})
                  except WaiterError as e:
                    # Request the same event but set PhysicalResourceId so that the AMI is not created again
                    event['PhysicalResourceId'] = physicalId
                    logger.info('Timeout reached, continuing function: %s\n' % json.dumps(event))
                    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
                    lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName=context.invoked_function_arn, 
                                          InvocationType='Event',
                                          Payload=json.dumps(event))
                    return

                  success({'Data': 'OK'})
                else:
                  success({'Data': 'OK'})
              except Exception as e:
                failed(e)
        Runtime: python3.9
        Timeout: 200

Lambda Logs:**Response { "errorMessage": "'ResponseURL'", "errorType": "KeyError", "requestId": "8e439e3f-a409-40d3-aecc-73c37e33ed7d", "stackTrace": [ " File "/var/task/index.py", line 78, in handler\n failed(e)\n", " File "/var/task/index.py", line 20, in failed\n cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, str(e), physicalId)\n", " File "/var/task/cfnresponse.py", line 19, in send\n responseUrl = event['ResponseURL']\n" ] }

the ec2 instance is runing in private subnet within the custom vpc i tried to make it public by allowing inbound in NACL and SG https requests.

# Inbound rules for Private NACL (deny all inbound traffic by default)
  InboundRulesPrivateNacl:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PrivateNacl
      RuleNumber: 100
      Protocol: -1 # Deny all protocols
      PortRange:
        From: 0
        To: 65535
      Egress: true 
      RuleAction: allow 
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0

AppTierSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
     GroupName: AppTierSecurityGroup
     GroupDescription: Security group for app tier
     VpcId: !Ref VPCIac
     SecurityGroupIngress:
      - SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref InternalLoadBalancerSecurityGroup
        IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 4000
        ToPort: 4000
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
     SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 443
        ToPort: 443
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0


tried to increase the execution time of lambda

Timeout: 200  #tried with 300,400,500,600


apply wait function to ensure that AMIfunction execute after ec2 instance is created by cloud formation following is the code for it :

AMICreate:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT10M
AMI:
    Type: Custom::AMI
    DependsOn: AMICreate
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt AMIFunction.Arn
      InstanceId: !Ref Instance



ec2 instance code running successfully

Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt AppTierSecurityGroup.GroupId
      VpcId: !Ref VPCIac
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64": !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -x
          yum -y install mysql # provisioning example
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal \
            -e $? \
            --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
            --region ${AWS::Region} \
            --resource AMICreate
          shutdown -h now

is there any solution to this ?
